# Why does the range operator not work with a QDomNodeList

Tags: c++, qt

So far, the range operator has worked on any Qt List type I used, except `QDomNodeList`. Since the range operator is defined as: *"Used as a more readable equivalent to the traditional for loop operating over a range of values, such as all elements in a container."* i can't see any reason why...

```
QDomNodeList domNodes = doc.elementsByTagName("peripheral");

for (QDomNode node : domNodes)
{
    qDebug() << node.nodeName() << "test";
}
```

...won't compile but the plain old for loop will:

```
QDomNodeList domNodes = doc.elementsByTagName("peripheral");

for (int i = 0; i < domNodes.size(); ++i)
{
    QDomNode node = domNodes.at(i);
    qDebug() << node.nodeName() << "test";
}
```

Compiler output seems rather obvious:

```
error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
     for (QDomNode node : domNodes)
...
note:   'std::begin'
     begin(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
                          ^
```

Plus the same error for `std::end`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use foreach with QDomNodeList in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914631/how-do-i-use-foreach-with-qdomnodelist-in-qt)

Comment: Similar question, true. But it is based on Qt's own `foreach` keyword and not the C++ range operator. Probably the answer fits both questions. The answer provides a link to `container classes` which is outdated and so far i did not find anything in Qt's reference about `QDomNodeList` not being a container type.

Comment: QDomNodeList doesn't provide iterators which the C++ range based for loop needs. Someone should implement that (and someone has, here : http://silmor.de/qtstuff.domfor.php)

Comment: Both `foreach` and range-based for loop require the structure to implement a `begin` and `end` which QDomNodeList does not. That is why you can't do so.

Comment: Alright. In both cases one probably has to accept the missing iterators. Since this is not a new problem i assume that this is missing for a reason (which i don't see). Not really satisfied with the answer to the other question but rather with the comment given by @acraig5075

Comment: @tobilocker Retracted the close vote because I agree those answers don't help you.